# Can we start Eclipse RCP application from single Main class?

Tags: class, rcp, program-entry-point

My question is : Can we start an Eclipse RCP application by a customized Main.java containing public static void main(String x[]){} method to run the RCP application ? There's no doubt the RCP application can be started as usual in Eclipse with default configurations.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you would like to do but if you want to run some dialogs/editors without running whole RCP you can just do it.

In example, if you want to open form/editor/preference page:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    new YourFormPageFromEditor().createFormContent(shell); // or some kind of code that insert here some UI

    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
      if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
```

}

Dialogs you can open just by type

```
public static void main(String[] args) {    
  new YourDialogThatExtendsTitleAreaDialog(null).open()
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you Mouster for your answer. But, i'm sorry to tell you that didn't mean what my question asked. If somebody have any further idea, please mind to post the knowledge.